# sequence contains no elements in xamarin forms for listview

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to populate a ListView from a data. 
In my XAML file I have written

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="FormDemos.Views.Feedback">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <Label>I am Testimonials Page</Label>

        <ListView x:Name="FeedbackList" />

    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

In CS file

```
namespace FormDemos.Views
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class Feedback : ContentPage
    {
        class City
        {
            public string Name
            {
                get;
                set;
            }

            public string State
            {
                get;
                set;
            }
        }

        public Feedback()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            var cities = new List<City>() {
                new City() {State = "FL", Name = "Miami"},
                new City() {State = "CA", Name = "San Francisco"},
                new City() {State = "CA", Name = "Los Angeles"},
                new City() {State = "FL", Name = "Orlando"},
                new City() {State = "TX", Name = "Houston"},
                new City() {State = "NY", Name = "New York City"},
            };
            FeedbackList.ItemsSource = cities;
        }
    }
}
```

Everytime I build this project I get Error "Sequence contains no elements". I have seen some online tutorials have the same code and running well. What's going wrong here?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You have to include controls inside a layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="FormDemos.Views.Feedback">
    <ContentPage.Content>
      <StackLayout>
        <Label>I am Testimonials Page</Label>

        <ListView x:Name="FeedbackList" />
      </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

I have written this [little article](https://acaliaro.wordpress.com/2017/03/11/another-common-mistake-using-xamarin-forms-and-xaml-property-content-is-null-or-is-not-ienumerable/) about this...

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes this happens when you have a ListView with Bindings and when you forget to add **Binding** keyword

Eg: `{Binding Name}`